# In Swift, What is the difference between var myArray: [myClass] and var myArray = [Array]()

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization

In Swift, what is the difference between:

```
var myArray: [myClass]
```

and

```
var myArray = [Array]()
```

Comment: In your second example, did you mean `[myClass]()` instead of `[Array]()` ?

Comment: var myArray: [myClass] is array of your custom class but the 2nd one is array of your abstract data type